# How to convert a document i.e .docx file into .pdf in python by taking the directory path as a user input in Python?

Tags: python

i tried this but in convert function "\" is getting passed instead of '\'. Ist i have taken input the directory path from user and then checked that if the file is a doc file or not after that by finding the lastindexof '\' and '.' I have extracted out the file name and modified it by replacing do from variable dpath which the directory where the pdf will be created ,after that im trying to replace '\' with '\' so that i can pass the value to convert function ,and that is where im stuck.

```
from docx2pdf import *
class convert:
 def doc2pdf():
   dpath="C:\ Users\ Rj rouma\Desktop\ do.pdf"
   try:
     n=input("Enter the file location : ")
     if(n.endswith(".docx") or n.endswith(".doc")):
       a=n.rfind('\ ')
       b=n.rfind('.')
       s=n[a+2 :b ]
       rep=dpath.replace('do',s)
       n1=str(n.replace('\\ ','\ '))
       rep1=str(rep.replace('\\ ','\ '))
       print(n1," ",rep1)
       convert(n,rep1)
   except:
       print("Check the location path correctly")

 if __name__=='__main__':
  ob= doc2pdf()
```

Comment: Your code has a class definition too much, you treat the escape character (backslash) wrong and you should use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for the handling of file paths. I'm not even sure what you're trying to do there, because the meaningless variable names `a`, `b`, `c`, `n`, `n1`, `rep`, `rep1`, `s` make the code very hard to read.

Comment: The title of your question is about DC to PDF conversion, but all you code seems to be doing is trying to (man)handle file names. Please concentrate your question on the issue you are trying to solve. Also, punctuation.

Comment: I just take the line `rep1=str(rep.replace('\\ ','\ '))` as an example why there is no easy answer for your question. Use `print(repr('\ '))` and `print(repr('\\ '))` to see that those strings are the same. The `replace` method of a string returns a string, so there is no need to call `str` on it. You're missing some basics of Python and unfortunately this is not the place to teach the basics.

Answer (score 0):

I've only been programming for 8 months, but within that time I've found my favorite way of getting and handling path objects is with the module *pathlib*, alongside *tkinter* when any user input is required (more specifically, *filedialog*). In my opinion, while the way you're going about it can work, I think it's hard to read, and therefore easy to get lost when your trying to identify parts of your function. Frankly, its more trouble than its worth.

```
from pathlib import Path
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

# Require user to select a file. Returns the full file path
filepath = askopenfilename(title='Select a document file.', filetypes=[('Word document', '*.docx')])
print('Full filepath:', filepath)

# Make the filepath string a Path object so you can use Path's methods.
path = Path(filepath)

# Profit
print('Full path:', path)
print('Extention only: ', path.suffix)
print('Last component in path: ', path.stem)
print('Direct parent of file: ', path.parent)
```

Outputs as:

```
Full filepath: C:/Users/User/Folder_A/Folder_B/word_doc.docx
Full path: C:\Users\User\Folder_A\Folder_B\word_doc.docx
Extension only:  .xlsx
Last component in path:  word_doc
Direct parent of file:  C:\Users\User\Folder_A\Folder_B
```

I haven't used docx2pdf so I can't help with converting the actual file, but pathlib.Path will allow you to slice up the path string however you need.

Comment: Your answer is well-written, and from my limited understanding of `tkinter` (I have not used it, but have used `Tcl/Tk` extensively), it's probably going to work. However, the scope of the answer is quite a bit wider than what the OP asked about. I would have (if I understood the question thoroughly, which I did not), tried to stick with boundary conditions that the asker provided (e.g., name of file comes from a variable). Rome was not built in a day :)

Comment: Thank you for the criticism. It was my first post here. I'll try to do as you suggested.

I also believe I didn't fully understand the question after looking at the example, but tried to provide the best answer I could that would help.